# rails password authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

First I am very very new to rails. so bear with any of my noob mistakes. Still trying to find the best sources for reliable information. Many things are a little outdated.

I was following the Rails [tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning#top) and working with password authentication. In my app i have Users, and Departments with a has_many through relationship between them. The relationship is called the manager_relationship. MY authentication and authorization for users works. The manage and unmanage button works to create a manager relationship. I have also set up each department with a secure password. I was hoping to require a user to enter a password for the department before the manager relationship can be created. I added a password field next to the manage button.

Models:

```
department.rb
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :department_name, :password, :password_confirmation
has_many :manager_relationships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :manager_relationships
has_secure_password
```

manager_relationship.rb

```
class ManagerRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :department_id

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :department

validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :department_id, presence: true
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
has_many :manager_relationships, dependent: :destroy
has_many :departments, through: :manager_relationships
has_secure_password
```

Views
department/show.html.erb

```
...
<div class="span8">
    <%= render 'manage_form' if signed_in? %>
</div>
</div>
```

departmnet/_manage.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(current_user.manager_relationships.build(department_id: @department.id), remote: true) do |f| %>
<div><%= f.hidden_field :bdepartment_id %></div>
<%= f.submit "Manage Department", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Controller: ManagerRelationshipsController

```
class ManagerRelationshipsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :signed_in_user

def create
    @department = Department.find(params[:manager_relationship][:department_id])

    current_user.manage!(@department)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @department }
        format.js
    end
end
```

The above code works. It successfully creates and destroys a manager relationship. But there is no authentication. Any user can manage any department. I would like to require the managing user to enter a department password to create the manager_relationship

Here is what i have tried.

departmnet/_manage.html.erb

```
 <%= form_for(current_user.manager_relationships.build(department_id: @department.id), 
remote: true) do |f| %>
##################This Was Added ##############
<div>
<%= f.label :password %>
<%= f.password_field :password %>
</div>
################################################

<div><%= f.hidden_field :department_id %></div>
<%= f.submit "Manage Department", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

ManagerRelationshipsController

```
class ManagerRelationshipsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :signed_in_user
def create
    @department = Department.find(params[:manager_relationship][:department_id])
            ########################The line below was Added ##########################
    if @department.authenticate(params[:manager_relationship][:password])
            ###########################################################################
        current_user.manage!(@department)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @department }
        format.js
    end
       ####################I added this##################
    else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid password'
        render 'new'
    end
       ############################################################
```

Comment: One Quick question have you are loading current user using session variable?

Comment: there is actually a before filter on the manager relationships controller that requires the user to sign in before they can create or destroy the manager relationship.

Comment: so current_user is present? so each manager_relationships row has password field? you want to add some password to manager_relationships table is that you want?

Comment: close. the password is on the department table. I am trying to authenticate with password before a manager relationship is created. That way a manager needs a password to the department before they can connect to it and manage it. I added the application controller that has current user in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that i added was correct. The problem was with the flash message that i tried to display after an invalid password.

```
if authenticate
else
flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid password'
render 'new'  <<I removed this line.>>
end
```

My code was trying to render manager_relationships/new but it was not there. After i removed this the button worked as planned. But the flash messages will not show up. I posted that in another question since it is another topic all together.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally since user is login you don't need password how user can come to your page.
May be you want another level of protection to set/unset data you can use

```
 @user = User.where(:email=>...).first 
 # Authenticating User sonce your email id is in session
 # You don't need to store password on manager_relationship
 # create attr_accessor 
 @user.authenticate(params[:manager_relationship][:password])
 # if user is authenticate then you can add/edit your data
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help. either i am not understanding your answer or you are not understanding what i am trying to do. Assume that there is no model for Manager_relationship. I am also still confused on where the params are coming from. params[:manager_relationship][:password] <<what is this exactly?

Comment: I should have 2 passwords. one to sign in a user. and one to create a manager relationship. I do not want any user to be able to manage a department. The user needs a manager password to manage a department.